# Could Bjarne make mistake? (while explaining templates), or I still do not understand?

Tags: c++, templates

Guys, I'm doing excercises from "The C++ Programming Language 3rd ed." and on page 340 there is an example of function:

```
template <class T, class C = Cmp<T> > // Here is a default argument
// But as far as I'm concerned it's illegal to have a default argument in
// a function template
        int compare (const String<T>& str1, const String<T>& str2)
        {
        /*Some code*/
        }
```

So my question is:
Is there a mistake in a book or I'm getting this wrong?

Comment: Edited to remove the unnecessary abbreviations and unnecessary ALL CAPS for the sanity of all concerned.

Comment: @Cogwheel from current standard.

Comment: @Cogwheel: I get the idea it's illegal from the standard, 14.1/9, "A default template argument shall not be specified in a function template declaration or a function template definition".

Comment: *shakes fist at AJAX* I deleted my comment before I saw your responses... For posterity, I asked "what makes you think it's illegal?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the book is wrong in this case. It is indeed illegal to use default template arguments in function template declarations.

You can find the reference to that issue here http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_issues.html

Comment: And FWIW, they are allowed in C++0x.

Comment: Yes, that's probably what the "Voted to be corrected in the next standard" remark at the linked page is referring to.