# Bjarne's mistake in C++11 presentation?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a page from the slide (http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~nivelle/C++11_design_Wroclaw.pdf) that Bjarn Stroustroup presented.

[image]

The issue is that this code doesn't compile, but this does:

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T> class Vector : vector<T> {
    using vector<T>::vector; // inherit all constructors
    // ... 
};
```

This is the error message:

```
generality.cpp:8:11: error: 'vector' is not a class, namespace, or scoped enumeration
    using vector::vector<T>; // inherit all constructors
          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:477:29: note: 'vector' declared here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY vector
```

Is this Bjarne's mistake, or am I missing something?

The compiler that I use is clang on Mac OS X 10.10.

```
clang++ -x c++ -lc++ -std=c++11 -o
```

It looks like that he makes some mistakes: [Could Bjarne make mistake? (while explaining templates), or I still do not understand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311528/could-bjarne-make-mistake-while-explaining-templates-or-i-still-do-not-under).

Comment: sure, looks like a simple typo?

Comment: he made a mistake.  He said in another talk something like "I haven't figured out how to run my slides through a compiler yet" in regards to a `template <typename T, U>`, it happens.

Comment: "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it." --Donald Knuth

Comment: Not sure why you removed `std::` and added a `using namespace` declaration. Surely it would have been best to focus on the specific issue, rather than changing multiple things at once?

Comment: Oh and you don't need to "prove" that Bjarne can make mistakes: he's a human, not a god!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a typo. With `using vector<T>::vector;` you are selecting the constructor, `vector`, from the template class `vector<T>`. The other way around makes little sense with regards to `std::vector`.

Comment: You can define the constructor via a template-id, e.g. `template<typename T> struct foo { foo<T>() {} };`, so it makes at least some sense to me to expect `using foo::foo<T>;` to refer to the constructor as well. The nested-name-specifier in the original example is illegal however, since the injected-class-name of `vector` won't be found in the *dependent* base class.